# Excel Custom Function not totalling properly

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks in advance for any advice/tips/tricks.

Currently I'm working for a school in NJ and they have doing some data analysis multiple times a year. I use this code snippet repeatedly

```
countif(RANGE, "YES")/countif(RANGE,"<>")
```

I'm trying to make these codes shorter by using a custom function addin and I've got the range passing down I just can't get the totaling of "yes" to work right. Any help would be appreciated.

My custom count if function

```
Function CCountif(rng As Range)
Dim cell As Range
Dim Total As Integer
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = "YES" Then
    Total = Total + 1
End If
Next cell
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what your function is supposed to be equal TO. I suppose you want it to return Total. In that case write this at the end:

```
CCountif = Total
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told it what to output - so your answer is always going to be 0.

To fix just add `CCountif = Total` after closing your loop